# Get username from SharePoint User field in List

Tags: sharepoint, moss, workflow, workflow-foundation

I have a custom sharepoint workflow that I'm developing in Visual Studio. The workflow is running against a document library which has a custom content type connected to it. The content type includes a user lookup field ("owner").

I'm trying to have my workflow assign a task to the "owner" lookup field. However, I've only been able to get the display name for the user, not the account username.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you post some of the code?

Comment: Managed to find what I needed. The following block of code will return an SPUser item, which you can use to get any user information you like (ie. account name, which was needed to assign the task). "key" is the field/column that contains the user you want.

private static SPUser GetSPUser (SPListItem item, string key) {
 SPFieldUser field = item.Fields[key] as SPFieldUser;

 if (field != null) {
  SPFieldUserValue fieldValue = field.GetFieldValue (item[key].ToString ()) as SPFieldUserValue;
  if (fieldValue != null) {
   return fieldValue.User;
  }
 }
 return null;
}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Refer to this [Article](http://jebass.blogspot.com/2008/11/how-to-read-spuser-field.html) on how to get the User Details from the Field.

```
public static SPUser GetSPUser(SPListItem item, string key) {
     SPFieldUser field = item.Fields[key] as SPFieldUser;

     if( field != null) {   
         SPFieldUserValue fieldValue = field.GetFieldValue(item[key].ToString()) as SPFieldUserValue; 

         if(fieldValue != null)     
            return fieldValue.User; 
      }
      return null; 
 }
```

Your Code should be like this

```
SPUser spUser=GetSPUser(splistItem,"Owner");
String sUserName=(spUser!=null)?spUser.UserName:null;
```

Comment: I needed to use: `SPField field = item.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(emailToken);
                    if (field.Type == SPFieldType.User)
                    {                
                        SPFieldUserValue userValue = new SPFieldUserValue(item.Web, sFieldValue);...`

Answer (score 4):

My solution:

```
public static SPUser GetSPUser(SPListItem item, string key)   
{
    SPUser user=null;   
    SPFieldUserValue userValue = new SPFieldUserValue(item.Web, item[key].ToString());
    if (userValue != null)
    {
        SPUser user = userValue.User;
    }
return user;
}
```

How To Call:

```
SPUser spUser=GetSPUser(splistItem,"Owner");
```

This is tested code and working fine.