# SharePoint - Doing a user lookup on GetListItems SOAP call

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, soap, wss-3.0

I'm using jQuery and the WSS 3.0 SOAP service to retrieve and display data from a list. I'm wanting to filter the data by the CreatedBy column. Here's my CAML query:

```
<Query>
<Where>
    <And>
        <Leq>
            <FieldRef Name="Created" />
            <Value Type="DateTime" IncludeTimeValue="FALSE">2011-1-8</Value>
        </Leq>
        <Geq>
            <FieldRef Name="Created" />
            <Value Type="DateTime" IncludeTimeValue="FALSE">2011-1-2</Value>
        </Geq>
        <Contains>
            <FieldRef Name="CreatedBy" LookupId="TRUE" />
            <Value Type="User">Smith</Value>
        </Contains>
    </And>
</Where>
```

When I execute this, SharePoint returns the following error:

0x80004005 - Cannot complete this action. Please try again.

Removing the user lookup resolves the issuer. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use their display name, then you cannot use `LookupId="TRUE"` or a `Type="User"`. It should be:

```
<Contains>
   <FieldRef Name="CreatedBy" />
   <Value Type="Text">Smith</Value>
</Contains>
```

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416164/get-user-url-using-caml-query/3418985#3418985) for more examples.

**Edit:**

Also, I just noticed your `<And></And>` node contains three sub-nodes. Each one can only contain two, which means you need something like this:

```
<Where>
  <And>
    <And>
      <Leq>
        <FieldRef Name="Created" />
        <Value Type="DateTime" IncludeTimeValue="FALSE">2011-1-8</Value>
      </Leq>
      <Geq>
        <FieldRef Name="Created" />
        <Value Type="DateTime" IncludeTimeValue="FALSE">2011-1-2</Value>
      </Geq>
    </And>
    <Contains>
      <FieldRef Name="CreatedBy" />
      <Value Type="Text">Smith</Value>
    </Contains>
  </And>
</Where>
```